# Class file has wrong version 57.0, should be 55.0

Tags: java, class, version

When i run my maven project in intellij i get this error :

Error:(7, 30) java: cannot access com.mycompany.dao.impl.SkillDaoImpl
  bad class file: /C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/com/mycompany/ResumeDbApp/0.1/ResumeDbApp-0.1.jar!/com/mycompany/dao/impl/SkillDaoImpl.class
    class file has wrong version 57.0, should be 55.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

Know anyone why it doing?

Comment: The class file was compiled with a different version of Java and the serialVersionId doesn't match

Comment: Try Build > Rebuild Project

Comment: @pczeus class version 57 is Java 13. `serialVersionId` is something else. The software you're using requires Java 13+. Version 55 is Java 11.

Comment: `SkillDaoImpl` class in `ResumeDbApp-0.1.jar` was compiled with Java 13, but you're trying to run it with Java 11. Either rebuild the jar file using Java 11, or use a newer Java version to run it.